# Unable to start debugging when Weston is launched

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code, wayland

Launching a debug session when Weston is launched from a command line ends up with following error:
Unable to start debugging. Failed to initialize debugger terminal.

I need to set a break point at the beginning of main (or use "stopAtEntry": true) and when stops I need to launch Weston manually and continue my debug session.

Is there any way to avoid it?

Ubuntu 16.04, C++, Visual Studio Code 1.17

Answer (score 0):

I found a possible workaround/solution to my issue:
launch.json contains an attribute called "preLaunchTask" which can execute a task defined inside tasks.json. This way Weston can be terminated before the debugging starts:

Task (tasks.json):

```
"taskName": "kill weston",  
"type": "shell",  
"command": "killall weston || true"
```

Launch (launch.json):

```
"preLaunchTask": "kill weston"
```

Now I need to find a way to start Weston after the debug session starts... any idea?